# Must release code depend on ebx being preserved over function calls?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, inline-assembly

I'm writing a DLL add-on for an application that internally has large parts written in assembly language. I'm mixing managed C++, unmanaged C++ and inline assembly.

I have just spent several hours debugging an issue that turns out to be that `ebx` is not preserved during a call into the main application. The bug only happens if the code runs in release mode and outside of the debugger. Release code in the debugger does not have this problem.

I have turned off all optimizations I can find for the Release Build, but it still depends on `ebx`. I have added `push/pop ebx` as a workaround, but this bug is sure to come up again. :-(

Is it possible to tell the compiler that `ebx` may be changed during a function call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the prototype for the function which reports that it conforms to a calling convention without actually conforming to the calling convention's rules for register preservation. You need to wrap calls to the buggy function inside your own function that makes it conforming (by preserving registers), and have everybody call the wrapper. `#pragma deprecated` will let you enforce this policy.

Comment: +1 Wrapper functions will also ease centralizing the eventual logging, marshalling, special cases, debug breakpoint setting, etc that will come to grow with ad hoc interfaces like this.